# Linux permissions in Apache on AWS Lightsail

Tags: wordpress, apache, permissions, amazon-linux

I can't update plugins with WordPress via the normal admin process.  I can upload media files.

My permissions look like this for the root and all subfolders

```
drwxrwsr-x webadmin apache ... mywebsite.io
```

Permissions look like this for all files/subfiles

```
-rw-rw-r-- webadmin apache ... whateverfile.php
```

If I update the owner.group to be apache.apache (with all same permissions), I can update plugins.  I'm totally baffled.  Thoughts?  Thank you in advance!

output of groups apache

```
apache : apache
```

output of groups webadmin

```
webadmin : webadmin apache
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing owner:group to www-data:www-data

```
chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress-folder
```

Comment: There is no user named www-data.